# I'm unable to view the right side of my website on a mobile device

Tags: css, mobile-safari

No answer to previously submitted question.

I'm unable to view the right side of my website on a mobile device. This is the basic coding for the html and container style. The problem lies somewhere within the style but I can't figure it out. I've tried several options but no luck. Please help.

```
      html, body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      #container {
      background-color: #000;
      height: 1054px;
      width: 1400px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: -20px;

      #header {
  background-image: url(images/header_wrapper.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1400px;
  float: left;
      }

      #content {
  background-image: url(images/main_wrapper.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 690px;
  width: 1400px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
      }

      #footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FF0;
  background-image: url(images/footer_wrapper.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: 64px;
  width: 1400px;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by quickly looking at your code i would say it has to do something with the overflow-x: hidden; or  max-width: 100%; that you apply to your HTML/Body tag at the top.

I think it is getting inherited somewhere so your overflow:auto will not trigger on the mobile device (and hence cutting off half your page).

If possible open your page on a developer machine and use firefox/chrome dev tools to run the page as a mobile device (so you can check the css) and then disable/enable till it actually shows like it should.

Comment: I was able to fix it, I just removed the max-width and overflow-x:hidden from the html body tag. I have checked marked and accepted your answer. Thank you very much.